# Warning in Visual Studio when i build it locally

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget-package, .net-framework-version

Ok I give up. I spent 30-40 mins on these warnings and wanted to ask the experts here as to what is the right thing to do.

My **csproj** and **package.config** files has latest versions listed.
I am scared to update the .NET Framework version from 4.7.2 to 4.8

I already have **AutoGenerateBindingRedirects** in my csproj file

```
AutoGenerateBindingRedirects::true::/AutoGenerateBindingRedirects
```

> Warning: *Consider app.config remapping of assembly "Azure.Core, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8" from Version "1.34.0.0" [] to Version "1.35.0.0" [C:\Users\SomeFolder\source\repos\Folder1\Folder2\packages\Azure.Core.1.35.0\lib\net472\Azure.Core.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.*

> *Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects" property to true in the project file. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=294190.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to one of our internal feed which has lower versions of same assembly. Removed references of our internal feed from Packagemanager which resolved the issue